# Port-Forwarding for Click'n'Load remote usage

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, iptables

I've got JDownloader running on my HTPC and access it via VNC.
The problem with Click'n'Load (CNL) is, JD only listens on localhost:9666 for incoming traffic, and the browser applications only send traffic to localhost:9666, so I can't use CNL with the VNC connection.

I have to redirect my PC's localhost:9666 to the HTPC's localhost:9666

I've read up on SSH tunnels, but failed to set one up to work. I also know this could be done with iptables, but don't know how. Do you know a solution to make a connection between both local 9666 Ports? Traffic would have to be redirected from the PC listening on localhost:9666 to the HTPC, making it available at localhost:9666 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have whole connectivity from PC to HTPC (no firewall in between):

```
PC$ ssh -L 9666:localhost:9666 user@HTPC
```

This opens an ssh session (destination: default port 22) from PC -> HTPC (you will get a console prompt in HTPC) and creates inside this ssh session a tunnel from the L(ocal = PC) port 9666 to localhost:9666 (HTPC).

If there was a firewall that would allow only outcome communications on port 80:

```
PC$ ssh -p 80 -L 9666:localhost:9666 user@HTPC
```

This way the ssh session has the destination in port 80, which is open in the firewall.